# Terraform module for creating app service environment Azure V2

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a terraform module that creates app service environment  using an ARM template and I am planning to move to terraform module **azurerm_app_service_encironment** as arm templates are getting deprecated.

When I search the terraform repo with app service environment [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs) , I get module **azurerm_app_service_Environment** and **azurerm_app_service_environment_v3**.  I am currently using ASEV2, how do I create that using terraform? I see V3 has a separate module, what about V2?

Also my ARM template is using params like dnsSuffix which I cannot find in [ASE](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_environment) terraform module but exist in [ASE version 3](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_environment_v3).

Comment: Have you gone through this terraform module for App service environments https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_environment

Comment: Your question is very unclear.Please provide more details what you are trying to do and achieve?

Comment: I have edited the question & added more details. Hope this gives more clarity.

Comment: There is no document available in terraform for **azurerm_app_service_environment_v2** but you are planning to Migrate to **App Service Environment v3** from **azurerm_app_service_environment_v2** using ARM so you can refer this document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/migration-alternatives

Comment: Also there is feature difference between **azurerm_app_service_environment** and **azurerm_app_service_environment_v3** so few features available in update version might be not in earlier version so that is the reason dns_suffix is not there in **azurerm_app_service_environment**
.

Comment: Even from using portal you only have option to create **App Service Environment v3**

Comment: After 31 August 2024, if you haven't migrated to App Service Environment v3, your App Service Environment v1/v2s and the apps deployed in them will no longer be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no document available in terraform for `azurerm_app_service_environment_v2` but if you are planning to Migrate `App Service Environment v3` from `azurerm_app_service_environment_v2` using ARM so you can refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/migration-alternatives) :

Also there is feature difference between `azurerm_app_service_environment` and `azurerm_app_service_environment_v3` so few features available in update version that not in earlier version so that is the reason `dns_suffix` is not there in `azurerm_app_service_environment`.

I tried to create app_service_enviroment from portal you only have option to create `App Service Environment v3`(Latest).

**Note : After 31 August 2024, if you haven't migrated to App Service Environment v3, your App Service Environment v1/v2s and the apps deployed in them will no longer be available.**